# Using Tomcat JMX Proxy from java client for starting/stopping web application

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

I'm trying to write a simple java client for starting/stopping application deployed on Tomcat using Tomcat JMX Proxy. Tomcat's documentation here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Using_the_JMX_Proxy_Servlet helps, however I can not pin down the exact piece of code doing that. Any help will be appreciated.